# Python list combination

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'd like to get all the possibilities to split the list `1 - 3`:

```
[
    ( 1, (2, 3, 4) ),
    ( 2, (1, 3, 4) ),
    ( 3, (1, 2, 4) ),
    ( 4, (1, 2 ,3) )
]
```

Now the best I can find is use `itertools.combinations(num, 3)`, but it will only give the second part of each item, that means `[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]`. are there other methods I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how general the problem you're solving is, the solution can be more or less simple :)

```
In [1]: nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [2]: [(x, tuple(y for y in nums if y != x)) for x in nums]
Out[2]: [(1, (2, 3, 4)), (2, (1, 3, 4)), (3, (1, 2, 4)), (4, (1, 2, 3))]
```

If there are repeating values in the list, use indices for comparison:

```
In [3]: [(x, tuple(y for j, y in enumerate(nums) if j != i)) for i, x in enumerate(nums)]
Out[3]: [(1, (2, 3, 4)), (2, (1, 3, 4)), (3, (1, 2, 4)), (4, (1, 2, 3))]
```

Comment: Nice approach, but won't work if there are repeated values in `nums`. For an even more general purpose solution, use `enumerate` and compare the indices instead.

Comment: @Shawn, that's one of the things I had in mind when saying it can be more or less easy :) I've added an example with `enumerate`, it doesn't look very pretty though. Can it be simplified?

Answer (score 2):

You are halfway there. You can combine the result with your original list using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) and [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
result = zip(num, reversed(itertools.combinations(num, 3)))
```

But if you want to use the first part is some kind of index only, there is no need for that. You can use the position of the element in the list as index (obviously).

Comment: What do you mean the order is not necessary? It looked like the number in the first part is always the one that is not in the list in the second part. Isn't that correct? To achieve that you have to combine both lists properly.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a simpler solution:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for n in range(len(nums)):
    print (nums[n], nums[:n] + nums[n+1:])
```

as a comprehension:

```
result = [(s, nums[:n] + nums[n+1:]) for n, s in enumerate(nums)]
```

Comment: The inner collection is a list instead of a tuple as shown in OP's example, but that's trivial to fix if it's important. Nice solution.

Comment: @ShawnChin: yes, `tuple()` is deliberately left as an exercise for the reader ))

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick but is probably inefficient:

```
>>> t=set(nums) ; [ (t.difference(x).pop(),x) for x in list(itertools.combinations(t,3)) ]
[(4, (1, 2, 3)), (3, (1, 2, 4)), (2, (1, 3, 4)), (1, (2, 3, 4))]
```